# Javascript function order

Tags: javascript, order-of-execution

Sooooo, I'm having a JS problem.  I'm fairly new to web development so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong with my JS.

```
//create script for #mainHeading focus @ pageload -- heading 1
    window.onload = function() {
        var mainHeading = document.getElementById("mainHeading");
        mainHeading.style.textShadow = '0px 0px 0px #fff'
    }

//create script for #subHeading focus @ pageload -- heading 2
    window.onload = function() {
        var subHeading = document.getElementById("subHeading");
        subHeading.style.textShadow = '0px 0px 0px #fff'
    }
```

So basically I wrote the function for my first heading to "focus" when the page loads.  Then I decided to add a second heading with the same function.  Now when I load my page only the second heading loads and not both.

Why is this??

Answer (score 7):

Because you're overwriting the first function. Don't set the property like that... use `addEventListener` or equivalent instead:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // First event handler
});
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // Second event handler
});
```

This method allows you to register as many event handlers as is necessary. Note that very old versions of Internet Explorer don't support it though, so you may need to feature detect it and use `attachEvent` in those old IE versions.

Currently, you are simply setting the value of a property. Consider the following code, which is effectively equivalent:

```
var obj = {};
obj.x = 10;
obj.x = 20;
console.log(obj.x); // 20
```

Answer (score 3):

You're replacing the `onload` function.

The right solution would be to add an event listener using `addEventListener`, they're additive :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function1);
window.addEventListener('load', function2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing your onload function, simply add instructions to it. Nice oldschool and therefore cross-browser compatible:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var mainHeading = document.getElementById("mainHeading"),
         subHeading = document.getElementById("subHeading");
    mainHeading.style.textShadow = '0px 0px 0px #fff';
    subHeading.style.textShadow = '0px 0px 0px #fff';
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the method on the second one. You need to merge them together:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var mainHeading = document.getElementById("mainHeading"),
        subHeading = document.getElementById("subHeading");

    mainHeading.style.textShadow = subHeading.style.textShadow = 
                                                  '0px 0px 0px #fff';
};
```

You can also do what the other answers did as well. That's seems nice too.